# IIS 7 Rewrite to different Application Pool

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, application-pool

There are a lot of topics on the subject saying that you cannot rewrite an incoming request to a different Application Pool in IIS 7 (one such post is https://serverfault.com/questions/220007/iis-7-5-multiple-application-pools-and-url-rewriting-403-18-forbidden).  A redirect will work but the requirement for this project is we cannot allow the user to see or search engines to index the redirected Url.

So the question is: is there any other mechanism on the local server that allows you to intercept a request before IIS has had a chance to begin the request processing; somewhat like the old ISAPI filters used to do.  A lot of articles suggest using some form of a Http Proxy or Software Load Balancer; both options are valid but can cause some overhead with physical and virtual resources.  To recap, the main goal is that we're trying to get requests coming from www.domain.com/(.*) to be rewritten to www.domain.com/{currentversion}/{R:1} where the root Web Site and the versioned Web Application are isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding you; but you want essentially a *Reverse Proxy*?  A way to rewrite the URL to avoid the search; where the client is generating the page resources as if it came from the server.  Which can be utilized from the `IIS Rewrite Module`.

All though, you may be able to just create two completely separate sites Example:

- `http://www.foo.com`
- `http://www.foo.com/en`
- `https://www.foo.com/en` <-- Input as if you were transitioning to `https`.

That way the `<sites>` are pointing to a separate directories then are both being handled as separate entities so you can create *blocked responses on that one page so it isn't found within the search engine*.

If my answer is off; let me know and I'll delete it.  But I think that should work; in theory anyways. [Also Squid and Varnish are applications that used to create Reverse Proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).